# error on getting the name of first sheet into the formula using macro excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have tried with the code below in Excel 2007 and it generates a run time error 1004. I have tried with different ways to solve but could not. Need help in solving error because each of my first worksheet is named different.

```
   Dim shtName As String
   shtName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
   Worksheets(2).Range("F2").Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS(&shtName!E:E,&shtName!A:A,"">="" & A2,&shtName!A:A,""<"" & B2)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should detach your variables from strings by putting them outside the "" marks.

So it is supposed to be

```
Dim shtName As String
shtName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
Worksheets(2).Range("F2").Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS(" & shtName & "!E:E," & shtName & "!A:A,"">="" & A2," & shtName & "!A:A,""<"" & B2)"
```

Comment: Yes, exactly YowE3K. i had tried to correct the code here, not in VBA. thanks for warning

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the value of your `shtName` variable into the formula, not the variable name itself:

```
Dim shtName As String
shtName = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
Worksheets(2).Range("F2").Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS('" & shtName & "'!E:E,'" & shtName & "'!A:A,"">="" & A2,'" & shtName & "'!A:A,""<"" & B2)"
```

(And it is usually a good idea to wrap sheet names in single-quotation marks to avoid problems if the name includes a space, etc.)